# How to find audio files from apps

Tags: audio, file-management

I have this app from Bungie, which is called Destiny, and it's a companion for their game.

The app has a really nice notification sound but I don't know how to find the audio in the file manager because the folder from /Android/data has nothing in it.

If it helps I also have 2 computers, one with Windows 10 and the other with Ubuntu 16.04.

My phone is a Samsung J5 2017 with Android 7.0

Comment: Any chance it's using one of your prepackaged Android system sounds? Go through the list and sample them.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone you can install [Show Java](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava) or [Dexplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexplorer) to decompile the apk. Usually such media files are kept in assets folder, but can vary on their development practices. On your PC you can use apk tool to decompile the apk and check the source there.